# Use HBase/Phoenix as an MPP

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

We are trying to set down our MPP solution, one of the thoughts is to stick to our Hadoop environment. So ruled out Hive, Impala etc. We laid eyes on HBase+Phoenix, Has anyone used HBase/Phoenix as an MPP in the overall solution? Are there any gotchas in this case?

Comment: It would help if you defined the exact **features** you are expecting from a "MPP solution". I am guessing that you mean Massively Parallel Processing (but that's not obvious), and that you further mean MPP *database* (as opposed to a number-crunching supercomputer for weather forecast, for instance). But even if I'm guessing well, what kind of DB features do you need?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Reasonable concurrency, data warehouse level SQL support, near real-time response.

Comment: OK, so please remove the `MPP` tag that is linked to "Microsoft Project"... and contact Teradata sales rep (sorry).